# Is there as way for an iphone app to store global application data in the cloud

Tags: ios, iphone, amazon-web-services, core-data, icloud

Is there as way for an iphone app to store global application data in the cloud?

I wish to have global data for an iphone application in the cloud. I say global as the data is not user based. It will be the same for all users of the app. This would allow me to update a small, normally offline, database for every user without updating the application. It would also allow me to crowdsource information sent from the app to central global cloud storage. I am revisiting iOS after a number of years absence.

Does apple provide a cloud solution that will do this where I can buy cloud space for my app?

Could I do this using a single user account for all apps? Are there simple AWS alternatives? Obviously security is an issue. It would be nice if the data was secure against simply sniffing the net traffic. An off the shelf solution would be nice.

Comment: You can use a CloudKit public database

Comment: This isn't a concrete question. Check out the dev videos on cloudkit https://developer.apple.com/videos/all-videos/?q=cloudkit otherwise you have AWS / Realm  or a homemade solution.

Comment: CloudKit looks like what I am looking for. Thanks. Its confusing how they talk about a "public" database. I think it means only accessible to the application.  I do not want it in a shared area of iCloud storage. I think this it will give me what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudKit "pubic" data is visible to all instances of an iOS or MacOS application. What makes it "public" access is not user specific. However, it can only be used in a way that the app developer chooses. It can therefore be used as cloud based application "global" storage. The developer can choose to have more than one app use the same storage. These could be a mix of iOS and MacOs applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can try AWS Amplify's [DataStore](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/datastore).

- Use the Amplify CLI to provision a GraphQL API managed by AWS AppSync and backed by a DynamoDB database.
- Configure your iOS app to store data locally in a SQLite database by using `Amplify.DataStore.save(...)`. The data will automatically get synchronized to the AppSync API.